# Saving the Project setting for TFS office add-in

Tags: c#, tfs, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have scenario in which I am accessing TFS from outlook. I am doing the customization using office add-in.

I don't want the users to give TFS connection setting every time they access TFS for the first time after opening outlook.

I want to create a setup form where I can save the setting using the client file system. How can i do that ?

can some one point to an example or code snippet.

Comment: Any reason you can't just auth as the user logged into windows? (eg specify no auth details in the constructor, just a url to tfs).

Comment: I don't want to save the credential. Instead I want to store the collection and project setting

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using MAPIFolder.GetStorage? You should be able to store any custom data in a hidden message in any folder, Inbox being probably the best place.

Answer (score 0):

**"I want to create a setup form where I can save the setting using the client file system"**

The connection details to connect to TFS use windows security, storing this info in a local file is not a good idea.

> When you make a connection to TFS with the Team Explorer, it will try
>   to connect with your current credentials to the TFS environment. There
>   are two scenarios in which you want something else:
>
> 1) You current identity has no access to TFS and you are prompted for
>   the credentials every time you make a connection to TFS
>
> 2) Your current identity has access to TFS, but you want to connect to
>   TFS with other credentials.
>
> You can achieve this by adding the credentials you want to use to
>   create the connection to TFS to the "Stored users and passwords". Just
>   add in there the address of you TFS server and the credentials. The
>   next time you access TFS, those credentials will be used.

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/05/21/Automatically-connect-to-TFS-under-another-user-account.aspx